# Which of the following would be an example of something that is quantized?

Tags: physical-chemistry, quantum-chemistry

[image]

How do we defind quantized there, why it is climbing a flight of stairs?

Thank you!

Comment: I would say it's just a bad question. Besides, there are no options *above*, so it's also poorly coded.

Comment: It's not an amazing question, but do you know what "quantised" is, to begin with? Were you taught it, did you look it up on Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum

Comment: These are the four options:A.sliding down a hill. B.climbing a flight of stairs C.walking up a ramp, D. all of the above

Comment: Yes, I did, I do not know why only climbing a flight of stairs can be an example of quantized, but why not option D? Thank you!

Comment: Very very pooor conceptual question.

Comment: Are the hill or the ramp levels quantized ? Is walking or sliding quantized ? Is hill sliding or ramp walking quantized ?

Answer (score 2):

It would appear the instructor is trying to draw an analogy between the quantization of an observable on the sub-microscopic scale and the macroscopic "quantization" of height.

To slightly improve upon your instructor's attempt (because walking up a ramp is ambiguous), let's say we are moving on roller blades. Then we can ask ourselves, for each given path (ramp, hill, staircase), at what points would we be stable? Only on the staircase will you find levels on the way up (or down) where you are stable (where you can stay put and your height is well-defined).

To reiterate, the instructor asked a poor question as it's not a great way to depict quantization. I don't fault you for answering all 3! I'd venture to say the only helpful part of this analogy is the idea of a stable state. Only on the stairs do you have multiple stable states that are discretized. The ramp and the hill have a continuum of states, and are thus do not have quantized states of height.